# Is there a way to set up a :has_many association through a callback or other method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

More specifically, let's say I have a model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    :has_many => (xxxImages)
end
```

Where xxx can be one of different models in my application. For example:

```
class ABCImages < ActiveRecord::Base
    :belongs_to => User
end

class EFGImages < ActiveRecord::Base
    :belongs_to => User
end
```

What I'm basically asking is: is there any way to pick one of those models at runtime to be inserted into the User models has_many association? Or do I need to take the polymorphic route (which I've only read about slightly so I'm not too familiar with it yet)

Thanks!

Comment: picking it based on what?

Comment: For example if user A has an ABC type account, the association should be :has_many => ABCImages, if user B has an EFG type account, the association should be :has_many => EFGImages, etc. Although this is starting to seem like bad design

Answer (score 0):

I think Single Table Inheritance is the way you should go which will harness the power of having different models but rather store in the same table. The only thing needed for this is to add a database field called **:type**.

So, in you case, I would create a table names **base_images** and other two classes would be just a subclass of this class.

So, the migration for this base class would look like this,

```
class CreateBaseImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :base_images do |t|
      t.string :type
      t.string :url
      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now, after you migrate this, it will create a model base_image.rb, as below,

```
class BaseImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

That's it. Now, that we have the BaseImage we will create two different models namely **AbcImage** and **EfgImage** which would inherit from **BaseImage** class.

```
class EfgImage < BaseImage

end

class AbcImage < BaseImage

end
```

And our user class would look like this,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :base_images
  has_many :abc_images
  has_many :efg_images

end
```

With this code in place, you can create association called **abc_images** or **egf_images** to user through association which works like a single table. And if you were to call **base_images**, it would fetch all the images, irrespective of which subclasses they belong.

You will find this so much resuable that later if you intend to create **hij_images** association then creating class HijImage and inheriting it from the **BaseImage** class and it simply works. By, the way there is no magic here, rails stores the name of the class into the type field in database. And so when you query for a certain class, it creates the predicate with type and the name of the class.

Comment: This make's sense but what I was trying to do is avoid having User contain any associations specific to xxx_images and only with base_images, if that would be possible. So if I did add an hij_images later on, I wouldn't have to modify User. To sort of separate it all out. I'm not too familiar with rails as I have been working with it for a couple of months.